# ConnectivityManager can't requestNetwork/bindProcessToNetwork in Oreo

Tags: java, android, wifi

After developing a working system in 6.0 (S6) I'm testing the same code in 8.0 (S9) and I've noticed that `ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()` is no longer doing anything.

Here is the function I'm using:

```
public static void enableWifi() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        request.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(
                request.build(),
                new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                        Log.i(TAG, "bindProcessToNetwork called");
                    }
                },
        30000
        );
    }
```

after calling this function, I check to see whether the connection has been switched to Wifi for 20 seconds:

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
enableWifi();

long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (!MainActivity.getNetworkClass(mContext).contains("WIFI")) {
       if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time > 20000) {
             Log.i(TAG, "connection timed out");
       }
}
```

After the timeout I'm still on the 4G network, wifi is never truly enabled. All logs shown above are called, yet the network state never changes to Wifi.

The manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Edit:

After much frustration I was able to establish a connection once using this setup, but not again since. I am not sure where to even begin troubleshooting this and assume it's a bug in 8.0 until I find otherwise.

Comment: Do you have the `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` permission declared in your Manifest?

Comment: @TheWanderer yup, it would never work on Android 6 without that. Updating the question

Comment: Does your Log in `onAvailable()` get called?

Comment: @TheWanderer every time, yes

Comment: So the issue is probably with `connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)`. The comments in the source say that will return false if the Network object passed to it is invalid.

Comment: @TheWanderer thanks for the lead, I'll look into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183196/discussion-between-star-trac-and-thewanderer).